# Controlling 60v with mosfet through pwm

Tags: voltage, mosfet, raspberry-pi, mosfet-driver

I got this setup for controlling high voltage with PWM through a Mosfet ranging from 0-60v.
[image]

Im using the [PCA9685](https://www.adafruit.com/product/815) for generating the PWM signals and then the [mosfet FQP30N06L](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/FQP30N06L?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduji0fg%2FlrI0nk1olBaTBVmAwVSKddLwzfQ%3D) for controlling the external voltage. So far I have only tried the current setup with lower voltage (12v) which works fine. But with the [Mosfet FQP30N06L](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/FQP30N06L?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduji0fg%2FlrI0nk1olBaTBVmAwVSKddLwzfQ%3D) I am using the maximum voltage rating is 60v. This might be a problem with 60V since a spike most likely would kill the Mosfet.

So i am considering using another Mosfet. I saw this [mosfet IRF3710PBF](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-IR/IRF3710PBF?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduh0FNvlHHLaBRz0EWgIFiQbgqtpFvucKtpxxzBZLA7WVQ%3D%3D) and wounder if that would be a better pick since it has maximum voltage rating 100v?

Am I correct when I am saying exchanging the FQP30N06L with the IRF3710PBF, connected the same way would be a good pick?

**UPDATE:**
I just saw as well that the [IRF3710PBF](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Infineon-IR/IRF3710PBF?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduh0FNvlHHLaBRz0EWgIFiQbgqtpFvucKtpxxzBZLA7WVQ%3D%3D) has a Gate-Source Threshold at 2v which might mean that IRF3710PBF might not fully switch on. Any other Mosfet suggestion would be great!

Comment: Maybe but using a 60V FET would be a bad pick

Comment: Yes maybe. I just saw as well that the IRF3710PBF has a Gate-Source Threshold at 2v which might mean that IRF3710PBF will not fully switch on. Any other suggestion would be great!

Comment: NO You do the homework and find a suitable logic level power FET

Comment: Your design will not work, the (assumed) drain of the MOSFET is not connected to anything other then the volt meter. I schematic would be much easier to follow then this frizzy thing. I definitely would not use a 60V MOSFET in a 60V circuit.  I believe 60V is the nominal voltage of the circuit, anything above that even for a short time will damage it. It might not fail immediately, but it will fail. Use a 80V or a 100V MOSFET, preferably the later.

Comment: Probably one of the most important things to do when trying to size a MOSFET is to look at the Maximum Safe Operating Area graph. The FQP30N60L for instance, can only operate under about 1 A when running at 60 V. The IRF3710PBF can maybe get up to 2 A when operating at 60V. This is all assuming that it has a proper heat sink.

Comment: The ON threshold voltage is usually less useful that the current vs threshold voltage graphs in the datasheet.  You want your MOSFET to be solidly ON at low Rds, not just ON.  Watch your gate capacitance too and find out how strong your drive circuit is.  The higher the PWM frequency, the harder you have to drive the MOSFET gate capacitor to make sure switching time is low compared to ON+OFF time.